# Countable intersection of arbitrary dense subsets

Tags: general-topology

A **Baire space** is one for which each countable intersection of open dense subsets is non-empty.

I am interested in whether a name has been given to general (by which I mean not necessarily Hausdorff) topological spaces for which every countable intersection of **arbitrary** dense spaces is non-empty.

If there is even a characterization of these spaces, or any consequences deriving from this property, I'd also be most interested in a reference (paper or otherwise) if one is known.

Answer (score 0):

First, in a Baire space the countable intersection of open dense subsets is eben dense, not just non-empty (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space), e.g.).

There is a notion of [resolvable spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvable_space) of which there are quite a lot. In such spaces we can write $X$ as a union of two disjoint dense subsets (like irrationals and rationals for the reals), and so there this property certainly fails.

If a space has at least one isolated point $p$, then this $p$ will be in all dense subsets, so also in their intersection (if you only care about non-emptiness), and many spaces without isolated points (all locally compact ones, and all metrisable ones too, I think). But I'm not aware of a lot of theory on this.